# How to check existence of swap file in .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I have in my home directory on Windows a `task.otl`, which is a kind of Todo list, using the [vim-outliner](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3515) format.

When launching gvim without argument, I automatically load it. However, I would like to only open it once. So I want to check in my `.vimrc` the existence of the swap file before opening it in a new session.

Whatever I do,

```
 :echo filereadable(expand("$HOME/task.otl"))
```

always correctly returns `1`. It works with other file in my home directory as well.

However if I try,

```
 :echo filereadable(expand("$HOME/.task.otl.swp"))
```

it always returns `0`. (even when the file is present in the directory)

For completeness, I have also tried with `glob()`

```
:echo glob(expand("$HOME/task.otl"))
```

returns the full path

```
:echo glob(expand("$HOME/.task.otl.swp"))
```

returns an empty string...

Further tests :  `test.swp` is not found & `test.fwp` is found. So this is definetely an issue with extension.

I have tried `set suffixes -= .swp` with no success.

Removing `.swp` from `wildignore` allows to find `test.swp` with glob() but not `.task.otl.swp`...

So my question would be how to test the existence of swap file in Vimscript ? Other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: just curious, does window recognize `$HOME` ? also think about this scenario, you are working on your `task.otl`, then for whatever reason, you got a blue-screen. you rebooted, so you never gonna open your task.otl until you manually delete the `.swp` file.

Comment: @Kent : yes, it works and expands something like `C:\Documents and Settings\user`. `~` works as well actually.

Comment: @Kent : I also use a `:Task` command to load it unconditionally, so in the worst case, I will erase the .swp at that time.

Comment: thanx for the answer! good to know it. just took a look `:h $HOME`.. ;)

Comment: On my windows installation of gvim the swap would be `task.otl~`. have you checked that your swap file is `.task.otl.swp` ?

Comment: @Eineki : I do have a `.task.otl.swp`

Comment: @XavierT. Never mind I was wrong, that was the backup file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildignore ignores the file starting with `.` too.

I just managed to have the correct behaviour using

```
:set wildignore-= .*
```

Comment: My wildignore was not including .* but it seems that I did something wrong during my initial test, because removing `*.swp` does work on my installation. So thanks for doing the test.